# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 3, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror

I'm trying to create a script that will clear cells back to `0` after running a calculation. You can see below is what I have:

```
function ClearCells() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Go vs. Perpetual Margin Calc Kevin 2020');
  sheet.getRange('C4:C6').clearContent();
   
}
```

This is the error I got:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 3, file "Code")
```

Comment: Sheet name is incorrect or there is no sheet with the said name.

Comment: OK i fixed that. How would i make it for multiple cells? I also need G9:G12 and J9 to be cleared. Also, is there a way to have it clear back to a value of 0?

Comment: We prefer new posts for new questions. See [ask]. Research ``rangelist`` and `setValue`.

Answer (score 0):

As @TheMaster said you have to use [rangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list) and [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setvaluevalue) to modify the values of those ranges.

```
function ClearCells() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Go vs. Perpetual Margin Calc Kevin 2020');
  var rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(['G9:G12', 'J9']);
  rangeList.setValue(0);
}
```